# git: 'Repository not found error' for private repository on Github

Tags: git, github

I am facing the following problems while trying to push a branch in origin.
So, what I have done is, created a new branch and add a commit on it. Then tried to push. It shows,

> fatal: The current branch Hotfix/Update_ducusign_semail_subject_line
>   has no upstream branch. To push the current branch and set the remote
>   as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin Hotfix/Update_ducusign_semail_subject_line
> ```

Then, I run the following command

```
git push --set-upstream origin Hotfix/Update_ducusign_semail_subject_line
```

But it gives the following error,

> remote: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/nalam-nmef/NextGenTPR.git/' not found

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: This user has no repo named `NextGenTPR`. https://github.com/nalam-nmef?tab=repositories

Comment: It is a private repo

Comment: (I deleted my answer because it turns out SSH is not required to use private repos.)

Comment: Is your user name and email address set up correctly in your local repo? What's the output of `git config user.name` and `git config user.email`?

Comment: yes, user.name and user.email is configured correctly

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` are irrelevant when running `git push`: they matter only when making new commits, and `git push` does not make any new commits. What does matter depends on whether you use ssh or https. For ssh, make sure that ssh authentication is working. For https, look at how you've configured https authentication credentials—there are lots of ways to do that, and they are OS-dependent—and then proceed from there.

Comment: You have the write access on the repo and not only read access, right?

Comment: Yes, I have the read and write access

Answer (score 8):

Github does not support connections via HTTPS to private repositories, if you do not supply the correct credentials.

You have two options now:

1. Switch to SSH and make sure your SSH key is available in your [Github settings](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh):
   `git@github.com:nalam-nmef/NextGenTPR.git`
2. Supply credentials for the HTTPS variant by using [personal access tokens](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line):
   `https://nalam-nmef:[your-private-access-token-here]@github.com/nalam-nmef/NextGenTPR.git/`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily authenticate with the github cli:

https://cli.github.com/

Comment: The best and easiest method. Thanks @Arnaud

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything and it didn't work so I installed GitHub Desktop, https://desktop.github.com/

I would add and commit files with Git Bash and then push with GitHub Desktop.